# Determine the history/origin of a software already installed in Ubuntu: deb, snap, AppImage, else?

Tags: apt, 18.04, snap, flatpak, appimage

I have a software I installed long time ago. I do not remember how I installed it: was it through the command line `apt`,through the software center, with `snap` or even `AppImage`?

I am looking for a quick and efficient way to know the origin of an application already installed.

Comment: `whereis`, `stat` will give date, and `file` will give type.  I don't have appimage or flatpak's installed so don't know if it'll work for those (it worked for the bin (debs) & snaps I looked at).  I would prefer logs, but `apt` and `snap` logs are completely separate.

Comment: if you never clear cache for `.history_bash` ,you can try `history |grep <package>`

Comment: whereis, which is nice, seems to cover apt and snap but not flatpak and AppImage

Answer (score 1):

Load the software center and look for the application. If the application shows up there, you know it was installed by one of the supported ways, `apt` or `snap`. Also manually installed .deb packages may show up there.

Some packages installed through `apt` are not visible in software center. You [can use `apt`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages) or Synaptic package manager (not installed by default) to see whether these packages are installed or not.

All other ways of installing packages are not officially supported by the distribution. If you installed through flatpak, you can list packages with `flatpak list`. Even these packages may show up in the Software Center if you installed integration of flatpak with Software Center.

For other packages outside of any package system, there is no way to directly know the source. You may have compiled the package or have used an installation script that copies application files to your system directories. Appimages are run from a directly executable image file which is somewhere on the system in a place where you or your sysadmin placed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
apt-cache policy <pkgname>

snap list [pkgname]
```

Comment: this needs you to know from where you installed it in the first place ('apt' or 'snap')

Comment: @theworldisnotflat you might even have installed from both. You will know, after you run the commands.